# NameError (uninitialized constant BCrypt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, bcrypt, rails-console

I keep receiving this error in rails console when I attempt to create a password.

```
BCrypt::Password.create("foobar")
```

```
NameError (uninitialized constant BCrypt)
```

My gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.1'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7' 

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem "active_model_serializers"
gem "jwt"
```

My user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    belongs_to :school
    has_many :user_courses
    has_many :courses, through: :user_courses  
    has_many :user_resources
    has_many :resources, through: :user_resources
  end
```

My user schema:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "category"
    t.integer "school_id"
    t.boolean "permission", default: true
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Any ideas why this error is occurring? I tried requiring bcrypt in my users model as well but still no luck.I tried Password.new as well but still nothing. Not sure what else to do at this point any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you run bundle install?  Any reason you have locked BCrypt to such an old version?

Comment: That is the version a `rails new` gives you out of the box

Comment: Make sure you restart your server after running `bundle install`.